# CONCAT Results Based on DISTINCT Email Address & MIN Date

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to concatenate the skus from a customer's first purchase order.

However, what I've written just keeps returning the skus from their latest purchase order as opposed to the first.

```
SELECT customer_email
     , total_line_items
     , GROUP_CONCAT(sku SEPARATOR ",")
     , MIN(created_at)
  FROM shopify_unified_v3 main
 WHERE created_at = 
          (SELECT MIN(created_at) 
             FROM shopify_unified_v3 
            WHERE customer_email = main.customer_email)
 GROUP 
    BY customer_email;
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Added: This is the view I'd created for shopify_unified_v3

```
CREATE VIEW shopify_unified_v3 AS
SELECT    `order_id`,
       a.customer_email,
       a.total_line_items,
       a.subtotal_price,
       a.created_at,
       a.fulfillment_status,
       `product_id`,
       c.title,
       c.product_type,
       c.product_size,
       c.product_price,
       c.sku,
       c.published_state
FROM    shopify_orders AS a
         INNER JOIN `shopify_orders_items` AS b
           USING(`order_id`)
       INNER JOIN `shopify_products` AS c
           USING(`product_id`)
       WHERE NOT fulfillment_status = 'refunded'
                     AND NOT fulfillment_status = 'voided'
                     AND NOT fulfillment_status = 'fraud'
                     AND NOT subtotal_price <= 0
                     AND NOT customer_email ='';
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What is the data type for the column='created_at'? Have you checked (SELECT MIN(created_at) 
             FROM shopify_unified_v3 
            WHERE customer_email = main.customer_email) if returned the first purchase date?

Comment: Show your database structure.

Comment: @Sphinx It's a TIMESTAMP in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format

Comment: Have you checked whehter (SELECT MIN(created_at) FROM shopify_unified_v3 WHERE customer_email = main.customer_email) returned correct rows (first purchase)?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Update: Used LIMIT instead of TOP 
In your inner query (sub-query), select only the oldest record by using ORDER BY clause. It should look something like this:

```
SELECT customer_email, 
    total_line_items, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(sku SEPARATOR ","), 
    created_at
FROM shopify_unified_v3 main
WHERE created_at = 
        (
            SELECT created_at
            FROM shopify_unified_v3
            WHERE customer_email = main.customer_email
            ORDER BY created_at
            LIMIT 1
        )
GROUP BY customer_email;
```

Comment: 1. it should return same result between min/max() and [top 1] with  [order by] at this scenario? 2. Mysql doesn't support 'top' keyword.

Comment: This is MySQL.  There's no `TOP` in MySQL.  Don't give solution that doesn't work!!!

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. You can use LIMIT instead. Updated the answer above

Comment: @daBigBug It doesn't work sadly, it spits out the same results as what I've got above but with maybe 150 less rows...